# How to avoid certain characters in MySQL full text search?

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I have a column named `parcel_number` of `varchar` type. It contains values like `ab-cd-ef` and `uvwxyz`.  A search for `abcdef` or `uv-wx-yz` does not return those records.

How should I write the query to meet this requirement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This situation seems to be the result of a bad design decision.

As this column is not storing human readable content, but is to be used as an identifier, the content of this column should have a uniform structure, either with or without the dashes, but not mixing them! You'd also have a hard time having a UNIQUE constraint on this column...

I'd recommend stripping the dashes from the table:

```
UPDATE table SET parcel_number = replace(parcel_number,'-', '');
```

[MySQL replace reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace)

Then you only have to strip the dashes from the the search string too. I assume `ab-cd-ef` is the same as `abcdef`. Do note however that doing so means `a-bcd-ef` and `ab-cd-ef` will be treated as being the same.

Comment: Why would you expect a `varchar` having structure in general?  Regarding the actual question you may be right, but the wording here is too generalized, I think.

Comment: @dezso you are right, I tried to edit the answer, but this is not as easy to reflect the change you suggested as it first seemed to be... I hop the meaning got through. Did I succeed?

Comment: You did!  Worth a +1 now.